# Binding a type to Webjob SDK trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobssdk, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using Webjob SDK for serving an azure service bus.

It works fine and now I would like to start to parameterize the inputs to it.

I have been doing:

```
public static void ProcessTopicStatusMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%topic%", "%subname%")] BrokeredMessage message,
    TextWriter logger)
```

Now i would also like to add an additional parameter: endpoint. Something like this:

```
public static void ProcessTopicStatusMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%topic%", "%sub%")] BrokeredMessage message, Uri endPoint,
    TextWriter logger)
```

I figured that it would be possible by binding the URI type to the config like this:

```
config.BindingFactory.BindToInput<ServiceBusAttribute,Uri>(typeof(Uri), new Uri(myURI));
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Is this even possible or do I have to make my own custom trigger?

Comment: Do you need to bind this string  if it does not change ?

Comment: @Thomas It can change. I expect to get this from a config database

Comment: Yeah but it is configuration, you can get it when the job starts ??? Writing a binding trigger can be painfull just for this ;-)

Comment: @Thomas The only reasonable way I can see is storing it as a static field in the "Program" class and fetching it from there, but that feels a bit ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, you can declare a static field to store you uri or you can inject it using a DI container. The `JobHostConfiguration` has a `JobActivator` that allows you to use DI.

Here I am using [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html)([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/)) to create a custom job activator.

```
public class SimpleInjectorJobActivator : IJobActivator
{
    private readonly Container _container;

    public SimpleInjectorJobActivator(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public T CreateInstance<T>()
    {
        return (T)_container.GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Now you need to create a class that will encapsulate your function trigger:

```
public class TopicMessageProcessor
{
    private readonly Uri _myUry;

    public TopicMessageProcessor(Uri myUry)
    {
        _myUry = myUry;
    }

    public void ProcessTopicStatusMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%topic%", "%sub%")] BrokeredMessage message,
        TextWriter logger)
    {
        // _myUry is accessible here
    }
}
```

In you `main` function, you need to configure the DI container:

```
static void Main()
{
    ...
    // get the uri from the config database
    Uri myUry = ...
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register(() => new TopicMessageProcessor(myUry));
    container.Verify();

    var config = new JobHostConfiguration
    {
        JobActivator = new SimpleInjectorJobActivator(container)
    };

    ...    
}
```

Just notice that this is a very simple example. Let me know if it helps.